# jQuery losing hover with position: relative

Tags: jquery, css

I designed an dropdown sliding menu using jQuery. When on one page I added

```
position: relative  
top: -18px
```

for some div elements, they are on the top of the ul that was slided down. While moving mouse through the menu, when I intersect with those elements, jquery starts to sliding up the menu (seems that while moving through the ul I'm jumping to div that is on the top, so that's correct). Of course I don't want such effect. I tried with adding z-index, but with no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/2WHVT/ (I added black border to the date tag, which is destroying the menu). Sorry for the color and design, I moved it quickly, but the point is the same.

Maybe you have some idea?

Comment: You need to post more of your html/css and jQuery. Also perhaps you could make a live example with http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2WHVT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `z-index` to bring your `li`'s to the top. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/2WHVT/12/

```
#menu ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #820B0B;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /*add this*/
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was adding the z-index to the whole menu div and that didn't work... Maybe you can tell me why?

Comment: @deha: As I explained in the comments to one of the answers below. `z-index` will not work without the element having a  `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted could you please explain why? This solution works perfectly and is valid.

Comment: @mblase75: Yes it will. Look at the fiddle. Also here is a reference for you: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index. First sentence under *Description* `'This property specifies the stack level of a box whose position value is one of absolute, fixed, or relative.'`

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `z-index` to the `#menu ul` CSS and it seemed to do the trick. Like so:

```
#menu ul
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;  //THIS IS WHAT I ADDED 
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/2WHVT/10/

Comment: This does not work. If you run you mouse a long the top of the `li` you will see the drop down does not appear. This is because `z-index` will not work without the element having a  `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed`.

Comment: I am not speculating. Using Firefox 6 and Chrome 13 I have tested your fiddle. It doesn't work. The top half of the `li` does not trigger the drop down menu. Make sure you have the window wide enough so that `#NewsDisplay` is overlapping the menu rather than underneath it.

Comment: He only asked for the slidedown menu to be above the rest, otherwise I would have done as you offered.

Comment: I now see why your code above on it's own doesn't make sense. You have applied it to `#menu ul` and so it cascades down to the `#menu ul li ul`. It would make more sense to apply it directly to the `#menu ul li ul`rule that already exists, as that is where the positioning is declared.

Comment: Hey... It works, let it be... Your solution was chosen, mine is another way for future generations to see and contemplate...

Answer (score 0):

```
#NewsDisplay .news .newsDate
{
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    color: Gray;
    z-index:-10;
}
```

This worked for me. Let me know if you have a problem.

Comment: hm, no, the span disappeared (at least in opera)